# SQL query in PHP ( WordPress )

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need help with a SQL query in PHP ( WordPress ).
I have this data:

```
| id | kw_id | date         | position
| 1  | 1     | 2020.08.23   | 16    |
| 2  | 1     | 2020.10.02   | 17    |
| 3  | 2     | 2020.10.08   | 5     |
| 4  | 2     | 2020.10.08   | 6     |
```

and I need get two rows ( id=2, id=3 ).
Query criteries is two:

1. get row with max date
2. group by kw_id

when date have duplicate ( id=3 and id=4 ) then get row with min position.

### The result must be as follows:

```
id | kw_id | date         | position
2  | 1     | 2020.10.02   | 17
3  | 2     | 2020.10.08   | 5
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For legacy MySQL 5.* it can be little complicated. Below query that returns needle id's:

```
select min(id) as min_id
from tbl
join (
  select kw_id, max(date) max_date
  from tbl
  group by kw_id
) tbl1 on tbl1.max_date = tbl.date and tbl1.kw_id = tbl.kw_id 
group by tbl.kw_id;
```

result:

```
+========+
| min_id |
+========+
| 2      |
+--------+
| 3      |
+--------+
```

and now final query:

```
select * from tbl where id in (
  select min(id) as min_id
  from tbl
  join (
    select kw_id, max(date) max_date
    from tbl
    group by kw_id
  ) tbl1 on tbl1.max_date = tbl.date and tbl1.kw_id = tbl.kw_id 
  group by tbl.kw_id
);
```

and final result:

```
+====+=======+============+==========+
| id | kw_id | date       | position |
+====+=======+============+==========+
| 2  | 1     | 2020-10-02 | 17       |
+----+-------+------------+----------+
| 3  | 2     | 2020-10-08 | 5        |
+----+-------+------------+----------+
```

and here [live SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a1061809ea5272f54a360f6c1f62d05e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` provides one option:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC, position) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, kw_id, date, position
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The above call to `ROW_NUMBER` puts the latest date first for each `id`, and in the case of ties for date, puts the smallest position first.